# How to enable desktop icons in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, webserver, environment

[image]

After following these commands, my desktop icons are disabled. How can I enable them again? actually, I'm a new Ubuntu user please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Undo what you did and revert to the default extension with following commands

```
gnome-extension disable desktop-icons@csoriano-local
rm -rf ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano-local
gnome-extension enable desktop-icons@csoriano
```

Be very carefull with he second `rm` command: copy it here and paste it in the terminal. Sloppiness where a space is inserted on the wrong place could cause the command to delete other contents in your home folder.